# IBM MobileFirst Platform 8.0 app authenticity not working on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, authenticity

I'm currently testing IBM MobileFirst Platform 8.0 app authenticity feature for both Android and iOS environments, and Android version works fine with all the required setting and procedures but iOS version does not seem to work under the following environment and procedures:

- IBM MobileFirst platform v8 running on Bluemix ver 8.0.0.00-20161122-1902
- cordova-plugin-MFP 8.0.2016110713
- Test app: MFPStarterCordova

The app is archived into ipa file and authenticity_data file is generated using mfp-app-authenticity-tool.jar too for the ipa file. The authenticity file registration and related security check (appAuthenticity) setting are done correctly on Console, and I installed the ipa on a (real) iPhone device. (The app successfully connects to and gets token from the server as expected)

I changed a bit of html code - e.g. simple string value - and reinstalled the changed ipa on the iPhone device, but the server does not seem to check / detect the change, under the setting I did with the original app. - i.e. The changed app connects to and gets token from the server successfully.

Is there anything else to be configured or to change to make the feature work on iOS?

Comment: Can you confirm you have followed all the points described in the link:
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/application-authenticity/
to configure application authenticity?

Comment: Yes, I confirm that I did follow all the points mentioned in the link. One remark is, the server version, which is a bit older one with authenticity_data file base, can't be upgraded now, as the same version is running in production environment. As said, the same setting works fine with Android version.

Comment: Can you also confirm if you are taking your application update from AppStore or via a local distribution mechanism?

Comment: Local distribution. Once I created ipa (not .app) with registered app ID and prov peofile, the ipa is installed on a real iPhone device using iTunes.

Comment: Any update? This test should done asap to be applied to operation, and please let me have any updates and progress.

Comment: @RickChoi Putting asap doesn't get your work done here .. Open a PMR with IBM on this to fasten the process.

Comment: Will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use new version of Application Authenticity(i.e Dynamic Application Authencity) which is more advanced and easy to use in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 8.0.

Upgrade your Client SDK and Server to the latest iFix level to get the feature.

More details about Dynamic and Static Application Authenticity feature can be found [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/application-authenticity/).